# Trustline for account purchasing an asset on an exchange

Tags: stellar-core, assets, trustline, exchanges

I have so far found out that an account needs to have a trustline for an asset if it is to receive a payment of that asset (from a given issuing account).

Does an account need a trustline for an asset if it is purchasing it on an exchange?

The reason for me asking this is that I can set the trustline for accounts that I create in my app, for the purpose of receiving transfers of my token within my app. However, I'm wondering how this would play out if an account created outside of my app, hence without a trustline to my token (asset), would be able to purchase my token.

I am new to Stellar dev, so I could very well be missing something obvious in my understanding of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trustlines are where balances for all non-XLM assets are recorded, so as soon as you expect to hold a balance of any such asset, you need a trustline.

Comment: So would it be true to say that in order for a non-XLM asset to be held in an account, that account would have had to have been created via an app/platform that supports that asset (and by supports I mean 'creates the trustline in question for that account')?

Comment: The account can be created by anyone, and the trustline can be created by any app that the user trusts with his/her private key.